# Controlling HTML elements with python webbrowser

Tags: python

What i want to do is open a new browser tab with `webbrowser`or anything else, if possible and control HTML elements in the webpage opened, for example: fill textboxes, click buttons and read data from the webpage.

Comment: What browser and browser version, what OS and what version of the OS?

Answer (score 0):

Try to explore on selenium library [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

Below is some basic code to open a website.

```
from selenium import webdriver

BaseUrl = "http://google.com"
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(BaseUrl)
```

Further read the interactions [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html)